# How can I specify a section as NOBITS in linker scripts?

Tags: linker, embedded, elf, linker-scripts

My linker script is like this:

```
SECTIONS {
    .uninit : {
        PROVIDE(_uninit_start = .);

        PROVIDE(_stack_start = .);
        . += CONFIG_STACK_SIZE * CONSTS_HARTS_NUMBER;
        PROVIDE(_stack_end = .);

        . = ALIGN(4K);
        PROVIDE(_uninit_end = .);
    }
}
```

However, the output sections are like this:

```
  [ 7] .bss              NOBITS           0000000080357000  00158000
       0000000000034000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4096
  [ 8] .uninit           PROGBITS         000000008038b000  0018c000
       0000000001020000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
```

If I use `objcopy` to copy the elf file to the binary file, the output size would be much larger than it should be.

Now my question is: how can I set a NOBITS flag for my custom section in the linker script?

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify section attributes in linker scripts, only in assembly:

```
.section    .uninit,"wa",@nobits
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use NOLOAD linker directive.

```
SECTIONS {
    .uninit (NOLOAD) : {
    ...
```